# nvd3 bar chart - show bars with value 0 too

Tags: nvd3.js

Below is my Javascript

```
d3.json(sugarAPI, function(json) {              
            $("#id_rigdata svg").html("");

            nv.addGraph(function() {
                var height = 400;
                var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
                  .showTitle(false)
                  .tooltips(true)
                  .showControls(false)
                  .showLegend(false)
                  .direction(app.lang.direction)
                  .colorData('data')
                  .color(['#C2B84D'])
                  .height(height)
                  .allowScroll(false)             
                  .tooltipContent(function(key, x, y, e, graph) {                        

                      return '<p><b>' + y + '</b></p>';
                   });     

                    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Months');     
                    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Rig Count');

                d3.selectAll("#id_rigdata svg > *").remove();
                  d3.select('#id_rigdata svg')
                      .datum(json)
                    .transition().duration(500)
                      .call(chart);

                return chart;
            });
        });
```

Below is my JSON response

```
{  
"properties":{  
  "title":"Monthly Count",
  "labels":[  
     {  
        "group":1,
        "l":"Jan"
     },
     {  
        "group":2,
        "l":"Feb"
     },
     {  
        "group":3,
        "l":"Mar"
     },
     {  
        "group":4,
        "l":"Apr"
     },
     {  
        "group":5,
        "l":"May"
     },
     {  
        "group":6,
        "l":"Jun"
     },
     {  
        "group":7,
        "l":"Jul"
     },
     {  
        "group":8,
        "l":"Aug"
     },
     {  
        "group":9,
        "l":"Sep"
     },
     {  
        "group":10,
        "l":"Oct"
     },
     {  
        "group":11,
        "l":"Nov"
     },
     {  
        "group":12,
        "l":"Dec"
     }
  ],
  "values":[  
     {  
        "group":1,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":2,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":3,
        "t":"26"
     },
     {  
        "group":4,
        "t":"26"
     },
     {  
        "group":5,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":6,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":7,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":8,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":9,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":10,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":11,
        "t":"0"
     },
     {  
        "group":12,
        "t":"0"
     }
  ]
 },
"data":[  
  {  
     "key":"Monthly Rig Count",
     "type":"bar",
     "values":[  
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":1,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":2,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":3,
           "y":26,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":4,
           "y":26,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":5,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":6,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":7,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":8,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":9,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":10,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":11,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        },
        {  
           "series":0,
           "x":12,
           "y":0,
           "y0":0
        }
     ],
     "color":"#C2B84D"
   }
 ]
}
```

Output

[image: Output]

Here I am trying to show the nvd3 barchart based on my JSON data. One bar for each Month. Now, only two bars are showing up where the value is not 0. What I need here is to show all the 12 bars with empty bars. I need to display the labels where the count is Month is 0 as well.

Comment: Can you add your working code on a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) its easier to help

Comment: Yes, if you can provide working live code on jsFiddle, it will be easier. But, i saw a working example on plunker, in which you can provide a function for x, y axis. And in this http://plnkr.co/edit/U1wWbe?p=preview , i can see zero values are also displayed on the chart. Also, its not a good thing but you can do this  
**y: function(d){return d[0]==0  ? 0.01 : d[0];}**